# Referencing single elements of a list

Tags: cross-referencing, lists, enumerate, roman-numerals

Given a list like this:

```
\documentclass{report}    
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item [(i)]  property one
\item [(ii)] property two
    ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I have to reference single elements of the list inside a sentence. For instance: by property (i) we have that...

I'd like to know if it is possible to refer to a single point of the list ((i), (ii) and so on). In other words I want to know how to use `\label` and `\ref` in this environment.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I want to know how to use \label and \ref in this environment.

Comment: @Schweinebacke your answer helped me. I've modified the question, is it correct now?

Answer (score 8):

To refer to items in an enumeration list with Roman numbers without writing the numbers but using `\label` and `\ref` you can use, e.g., package [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)]
\item property one\label{pone}
\item property two\label{ptwo}
\end{enumerate}
See items \ref{pone} and \ref{ptwo}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

In comparison, with the also usual [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(I)]
\item property one\label{pone}
\item property two\label{ptwo}
\end{enumerate}
See items \ref{pone} and \ref{ptwo}.
\end{document}
```

you would get:

[image]